# How can I combine the rows of 2 tables using a query or code?

Tags: sql, algorithm, vb6

I am using VB6 and MS Access 2013, I think this is very simple but I am stuck on this for 3 days now.

I have two tables:

1. Cheks: {ChekDate, Amount}
2. Deposits: {DepositDate, Amount}

I can´t figure out how to get something like this:

```
------Bank Statement------

01/01/15  300   Dep
01/01/15  100   Chk
02/02/15  400   Dep
03/02/15  150   Chk
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thank you in advance for your time.
Gilberto.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question title? "Statemen like QRY or report in VB6" makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are looking for `union all`:

```
select * 
from (
    select checkdate, amount, 'Chk' as whichtable
    from checks
    union all
    select checkdate, amount, 'Dep' 
    from deposits
) t
order by checkdate
```

Comment: You can add an "order by" without having to use a subquery.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes -- Thx, yes you can.  This just reads better imo.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test it now.

Comment: Man, I owe you a cup of coffee! I have never heard about the unión all. Your code worked perfectly. Thank you very much.